# Can we draw a picture that divided into 3 part?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can we draw a picture that divided into 3 part like below?

I have no idea where should I start?

[image]

How can draw a random signal as shown in diagram above?

Answer (score 4):

These things are rather basic, so here is a start. The random plot can be produced with

```
\draw plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:3.5,samples=21] (\t,1.4*rnd-0.7);
```

and here is an MWE which contains most other elements as well:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=L]
  \draw[<->] (0,2) |- (3.5,0);
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (3,1.5) coordinate[pos=0.3] (x);
  \draw[dashed,red] (x) -| ++  (1,1) node[red,circle,fill,inner sep=3pt]{}
    coordinate[pos=0.5] (y);
  \path (x) -- (y) coordinate[midway](z);
  \draw[red,dashed] (z|-0,0) -- (y);
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=R,xshift=7cm,yshift=0.5cm]
  \draw[<-] (0,1.5) -- (0,-1.5);
  \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0);
  \pgfmathsetseed{42}
  \draw plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:3.5,samples=21] (\t,1.4*rnd-0.7);
 \end{scope}
 \path (R.south) node[below]{Sound};
 \path (L.south|-R.south) node[below]{Model};
 %
 \draw[line width=2mm,->,shorten >=2mm,shorten <=2mm] 
 (L.east) -- node[above]{Synthesis} (L.east-|R.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Thanks, actually where is to start to learn about drawing using Latex?

Comment: @aan - There are several manuals or online tutorials.  Also, each package comes with a manual   Finding them can be tricky.  I use a folder containing nothing but links (shorcuts) to manuals.  (I tend to forget how to spell them.)

Comment: @aan The pgf manual has a pretty decent tutorial. Other than that you can google this site for certain desired outcomes and look at the codes there. If the answers are by Jake, percusse or Mark Wibrow (just to name a few) you can be sure that the code is well written.